# Line break between icon and text even with &nbsp;?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to put a non breakable space between an icon and the corresponding text.

For example

`<i class="bla"></i>&nbsp;someText`

ignores the `&nbsp;` in lower screen resolutions and displays the text under the icon. 
Is there any other method to make sure that an icon and some text to the right is always in line, regardless of the available space?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a container and use the rule `white-space`

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"><i class="bla"></i>&nbsp;someText</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/6vs8sbf8/)**

Read more about `white-space`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: with white-space: nowrap; &nbsp; is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

the `<i>` element by itself is not a `block` element. Meaning, it would not try to take the whole vertical space it can get, unless you tell it to do so in your CSS.

Check if you have set the styling of `.bla` and see if its `display` is not `block;` ..

```css
.bla {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<i class='bla'>block i element -- new line after me</i>&nbsp;Some Text here


<br>
<br>


<i class='bla2'>non block i element -- </i>&nbsp;Some Text here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different rules depending on the screen size, you can use media queries. to have a space after your block "i" you can add margin or create a container that have a width of some lettres (using em unit).

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

```
<i class="bla"></i> someText
```

css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    i{
        margin-right: 0em;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 641px){
    i{
        margin-right: 3em;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you, that's actually what i was trying to figure out next!